# Silverlight LinearGradientBrush Color not correct

Tags: silverlight, lineargradientbrush

I want to use LinearGradientBrush to horizontal fill my Rectangle on canvas.

#### My code:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="200">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5" >                   
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="1" />                 
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

But I notice that the left-most color of red is not #FFFF0000, and it was #FFFE0000

[image]
So did anyone know why this happen?

Comment: thanks Huy Nguyen, I don't have enough Reputation to show the screenshot.

Comment: Did You try write red color in hex instead of literally red. For example <GradientStop Color="#FFFF0000" Offset="0" /> ?

Comment: thanks Jacek Gzel, but of cause I tried that using the #FFFF0000, and the result was same. that is difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradient is drawn using interpolation, so it tends to the color you choose but it does not need to draw it exactly. It also depends on the size of the element for which you use the gradient.

Workaround - set Offset property as below:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="200">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.01" />
            <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.99"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Thanks Jaroslaw Rejterada.